# Term for a verse in which the last line is composed of the last words of the previous lines in that verse

Tags: obscure-terms

I have been searching a while and I have a strong feeling there is a term for what I am describing but I cant find it!

An example of what I mean is,

[image]

Thank you for your time, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mobile autocorrect, fixed and thank you.

Comment: There should be a better word than *Consolidation*.

Comment: Are there any instances of this being done in published work, or is it just something you made up? (Knowing where it is used will help find critical works discussing the device.)